# How to create a new environment in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a new environment (build) for using it with hudson.

I'm doing this because I didn't want to mix up my test databases with hudson test database.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Assuming you want create the `hudson` environment.

1. Create a new environment file in `config/environments/hudson.rb`. You can start by cloning an existing one, for instance `config/environments/test.rb`.
2. Add a new configuration block in `config/database.yml` for your environment.
3. Update any other configuration file you might have under the `config` folder with your new environment, some gems create their own `ymls` under the `config` folder.
4. That's all.

Now you can start the server

```
rails server -e hudson
```

or run the console

```
rails console hudson
```

And so on.

If you are using an older version of Rails, the commands are

```
ruby script/server -e hudson
ruby script/console hudson
```

Comment: you forgot to specify that you also have to check your gemfile and create a group, for gems in that environment

Comment: also you need to set the secret_key_base in the secrets.yml file for your new environment

Comment: Also if you have different environments that use the same config/environment settings say production for example you could add this line to your new environments/hudson.rb file to eliminate the redundancy ([see this for more info](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3535-beyond-the-default-rails-environments)).  
require Rails.root.join("config/environments/production")

Comment: Don't we need an entry in `secrets.yml` file too ?

Comment: Just a reminder that you may need to set the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable. For example, on heroku, for a new environment called "staging", you could do it like this `heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=staging --remote staging`

Answer (score 23):

> Updated Answer for Rails 5

**Create new environment file:**

```
config/environments/staging.rb
```

**Modify the following files to add the environment key 'staging'**

```
config/cable.yml
config/database.yml
config/secrets.yml
Gemfile (incase you have stage dependent gems)
```

**The new environments can now be used as usual for eg:**

`rails server -e staging`

`rails console staging`

**Or to do conditional checks:**

```
rails console staging, Rails.env.staging?
```

Good place to start for creating new environment and to modify these files is to copy production settings.

Comment: In rails 6 > don't forget `config/webpacker.yml`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using webpacker in your Rails 5 app, also make sure to update your `config/webpacker.yml`. If you forget to add your new environment to `config/webpacker.yml`, it will just fall back to using your production config.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `config/environments/build.rb` which will contain the options specific to your environment.
Add your new environment's database credentials in `config/database.yml`.

Rock and roll!

Comment: Why not mentioned the file `secrets.yml` ?

Comment: Because `secrets.yml` means you hardcode credentials into your git repository, which is a very bad security practice.

Comment: Yes, I meant inside that file you also need to add the key `staging: ..` like `production` has right ?