# How to start rails server from a Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to start a Rails application from a Ruby script.

From the script, I would like to:
1. Use a database found in another directory (pass the ActiveRecord parameters for establishing the connection?)
2. Save logs to the other directory
3. Set the HttpServer port (not as important, but would be nice)

I've looked at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html and have considered writing a script that does a lot of the same work, but I assume there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the --env= parameter when you start your server, when the --env parameter can be something which can be defined specicically for your needs : 
`rails server --env=my_special_env`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369511/how-to-create-a-new-environment-in-ror) on how to do it: