# Rails 4 and postgresql schemas, how to run migrations for 2 schemas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

Say I have a User model, and I want to setup postgresql with 2 schemas:

```
test1.users
test2.users
```

Is there a way to specify the schema I want to use when running migrations?

```
rake db:migrate schema=test1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add an environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369532/229044), call it "test2", and define your schema in config/database.yml. Then run your migration with `RAILS_ENV=test2 rake db:migrate`.

Comment: I'm getting this error: ```ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in```