# Rails server not showing log output in custom environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, development-environment

I created a new environment called "superdev", which is just like development.

```
# environments/superdev.rb
require Rails.root.join("config/environments/development")
```

Problem is, when I do `RAILS_ENV=superdev rails server`, I don't get any log output. Even when I set `config.log_level = :debug`

I've set the Gemfile groups to include `superdev`, created the DB, and the environment works fine otherwise. Just no log output. What gives?

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369511/how-to-create-a-new-environment-in-ruby-on-rails?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: might be a dump question, but do you have a `config/environments/superdev.rb` with minimum configuration ?

Comment: Which file have you been tailing? I think rails by default logs to `Rails.root.join('log', "#{Rail.env}.rb")` so it the output should end up in `log/superdev.log`. You can check by running `Rails.logger` in the the console.

Comment: @SimonFranzen Yes, I followed those steps. Ben Yes I do, the contents are above. Max I'm just talking about the output in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to enable logging to STDOUT. You can use either an environment variable, or an option to the `rails server` command:

```
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true rails server -e <your-env>
```

or

```
rails server -e <your-env> --log-to-stdout=true
```

Logging to STDOUT is only enabled by default for the `development` environment, and needs to be explicitly enabled for others.